# Using *ngFor with JSON Angular2

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have a returned json object:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "product",
      "id": "e0267f46-9721-48fc-8ee0-b554d82cfb52",
      "name": "fwefwefwef", 
...and so on...
```

I process it with this as part of my service:

```
export class MService {
...
     products.data.forEach(element => {
     let product = {
             name : element.name, 
             sku : element.sku, 
             description : element.description,
              category : element.relationships.categories.data[0].id,
             price: element.price[0].amount

            console.log(product);
          })
      });
  let product = MService
    });
  }
}
```

Which returns each object individually:

```
{
  "name": "Bombay Sapphire",
  "sku": "bomsaph",
  "description": "A great gin",
  "category": "46569361-13477074f952",
  "price": 1999
}
```

I have a model:

```
export class Prod{

    constructor(public name:string, public sku:string, public description:string, public category: string, public price:number){}

}
```

And a Component for which the *ngFor loop in the HTML returns needs to display what the API returns.

```
constructor (private mService: MService){ 

    products:Prod[] = [MService]
  }
```

HTML:

```
  <div *ngFor="let product of products"> 
      <div>{{product.name}} </div>
      <div>{{product.description}}</div>
      <div>{{product.sku}}</div>
    </div>
```

I am getting 'unused label' and 'expression expected' errors in the component.

Comment: What is your actual result? How is it different from what you were expecting?  Two possible guesses from the limited info here would be 1) your 'product' object isn't a direct descendant of 'products' and you need to try something like 'let product of products.data' in your ngFor  2.) your ngFor is being run on an object rather than an array...that can lead to some unexpected behavior.

Comment: At the moment I'm getting an 'unused label' error message on the 'product' ( which makes me suspect I am not going from json -> HTML correctly). 1) this shouldn't be neccessary as it is run through the loop and returns the pairs listed above. 2) What would be the best way to convert it to an array? @ryantdecker

Comment: In your component `products` is being set to an array, which contains a reference to the `MService` class. That doesn't seem right. You need to use the instance of the `MService` instead:  `products = mService.whatever`. Note that I added "whatever" b/c you don't really show the API for MService, so it's not clear where to get the array of `Prod` objects from.

Comment: if you put {{products | json}} in the template instead of your ngFor*, what do you get?

Comment: @ryantdecker Same error. It is definitely "  products:Prod[] = [MService] " that is causing the problem.

Comment: @SunilD. I tried to do it this way but it doesn't accept the value after Products = mService.

Comment: You need to change that line so that it receives an array of `Prod` objects. We can't tell you how to modify that line b/c you are only showing a small snippet from the `MService` class. In that snippet you iterate over the JSON and create the `Prod` objects. What do you do with them after you create them?

Comment: @SunilD. I've updated that section. I'm currently first logging them and then putting them into mService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you want to extract some values from your JSON in objects and push each object to an array which you can iterate through. First of all, use interface instead of class, so your `Prod` would look like this:

```ts
export interface Prod{
  name:string;
  sku: string;
  description:string;
  category: string;
  price: number;
}
```

And instead of using `forEach` in your service, let's just use `map` to extract the properties you want, assign them to objects with **[`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)**, int the exact manner as you were using with `forEach`:

```ts
getData(){
  return this.http.get('src/data.json')
    .map(res => res.json().data.map((x:any) => 
       Object.assign({name:x.name,sku:x.sku,description:x.description,category:x.relationships.categories.data[0].id, price:x.price[0].amount})))
}
```

So now when we are receiving the data in the component, it's an array of type `Prod`, which you can use well in your template:

```ts
products: Prod[];

ngOnInit() {
  this.service.getData()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.products = data;
    })
}
```

and template:

```html
<div *ngFor="let product of products"> 
  <div>{{product.name}} </div>
  <div>{{product.description}}</div>
  <div>{{product.sku}}</div>
</div>
```

**[Here's a DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/agRhhiDsJp6A81PJTdQs?p=preview)** from where I got the complete JSON from your previous question:  **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44089614/loop-through-a-json-in-angular2-typescript)**

Comment: Thanks for sifting through and sorting my ineptitude!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help! :)

Comment: AHT_82 . hey! Justa  quick follow up, I had things working, as per your Plunkr, but had to rejig things a little:[link] (http://imgur.com/a/cZgw6). Going wrong as always - do you mind taking a look?

Comment: Hey! Remove `;` from `this.moltinService.getData;` and you should be good to go :)

Comment: Hey! @AHT_82 . thanks fo your reply. I get this error? Is this because I'm sending the request for data before the response from the authentication is returned? [link](http://imgur.com/a/TxiJe)

Comment: @DominicLane You are getting a 404 error from your request, which means that url doesn't exist. You need to check that. Seems there is some problem with the parameters, as you can see the url has the ending of something `[object...]`